# Scala: Re-use generic resulting from path-dependent type in path-dependent context

Tags: scala, generics, path-dependent-type

In short: The following does not compile (reason below), how can I make it work?

```
trait Simulator {
  type CM[T]
  def useCM(v: CM[_])
}

case class CMH[S <: Simulator,T](cm: S#CM[T])

class SimIterator[S <: Simulator](val sim: S, val cmhs: Seq[CMH[S,_]]) {
  cmhs foreach { cmh => sim.useCM(cmh.cm) }
  /*
  compile time error:
   type mismatch; found : cmh.cm.type (with underlying type S#CM[_$2]) required:
   SimIterator.this.sim.CM[_] Note: _$2 <: Any (and cmh.cm.type <: S#CM[_$2]),
   but type CM is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as +T instead.
   (SLS 4.5)
  */
}
```

The idea behind the structure is that `CMH` hides `T`-specific behavior from `SimIterator` where as the latter handles common tasks. `S` is used to force vlaues in `CMH` to have the right type without having an instance of `Simulator`.

In the `foreach`, there seems to be a subtyping issue related to `CM`. If `S#CM` is a concrete type we need `sim.CM =:= S#CM`. However, look at the following:

```
object Test extends Simulator {
  type CM[T] = Option[T]
  def useCM(v: CM[_]) = println(v)
  def mkCM[T]: CM[T] = None

  CMH[Simulator,AnyRef](mkCM[AnyRef])
}
```

We have now a `CMH` that we can pass into a `SimIterator` together with any `Simulator`. So apparently the typing of `SimIterator` is not restrictive enough. How can express (and use) `S =:= sim.type`?

**UPDATE**

This works, but cannot be used in the constructor (illegal dependent method type: parameter appears in the type of another parameter in the same section or an earlier one)

```
class SimIterator(val sim: Simulator) {
  def doIt(cmhs: Seq[CMH[sim.type,_]]) {
    cmhs foreach { cmh => sim.useCM(cmh.cm) }
  }
}
```

The upper example works, but is **not** what I want. `cmhs` should be passed-in upon construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily fix the issue by moving the abstract type member to a type parameter like this:

```
trait Simulator[CM[_]] {
  def useCM(v: CM[_])
}

case class CMH[CM[_]](cm: CM[_])

class SimIterator[S <: Simulator[CM], CM[_]](val sim: S, val cmhs: Seq[CMH[CM]]) {
  cmhs foreach { cmh => sim.useCM(cmh.cm) }
}
```

That way you avoid using the type projection, if you really need to keep CM as a type member please provide more detail explaining in which case you need a type projection and why.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Welcome to the "Bakery of Doom"! ;-)

There is two solution in this case:

1st, **put you Iterator into the cake**, so you can access the type directly:

```
case class CMH[CM[_]](cm: CM[_])

trait Cake {
  type CM[_]

  trait Simulator {
    def useCM(v: CM[_])
  }

  class SimIterator[S <: Simulator](val sim: S, val cmhs: Seq[CMH[CM]]) {
    cmhs foreach { cmh => sim.useCM(cmh.cm) }
  }
}
```

or 2nd, **encapuslate your Iterator in an other class**, making possible to access the path-dependent type:

```
trait Cake {
  type CM[_]

  trait Simulator {
    def useCM(v: CM[_])
  }
}

case class CMH[CM[_]](cm: CM[_])

class SimIteratorBuilder[C <: Cake](val cake: Cake) {
  class SimIterator(val sim: cake.Simulator, val cmhs: Seq[CMH[cake.CM]]) {
    cmhs foreach { cmh => sim.useCM(cmh.cm) }
  }
}
```

Once you are in the cake, there is no way to escape it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `Simulator` is used in a cake pattern (to bake a particular simulator with different models), that's where the type member comes from. `SimIterator` is outside of the cake scope and can use some particular `Simulator` implementations (type bounds not shown in this example) to generate iterated simulations while persisting the `CM`'s data (of type `T`) in between runs. Adding a type parameter to `Simulator` does not hurt from `SimIterators` perspective, but totally violates the cake-pattern's type abstraction. `cmhs` is heterogenous in `T`, hence the projection.

Comment: @gzm0 Ok, fair enough. that make sense. I edited my answer with the possible solution. Good luck with the cake :-) I personally try to avoid that pattern as much as possible, in order to avoid that bakery of doom.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. But isn't this just a simple syntax limitation? In the secondary constructor from my answer, it is perfectly possible to force the type as I want. Is there any reason this cannot be extended to the primary constructor?

Comment: @gzm0 yes this definitely a limitation, not really of the syntax but in the support of path dependent type. I think this could be improved in a near future (some path dependent type features are relatively new), but for a definitive answer you might want to ask the question on the scala mailing list :-)

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE** someone come up with a better solution. (Yes, a `useEm` equivalent could also be done in the public constructor, but this allows to call it again).

```
class SimIterator[S <: Simulator] private (
    val sim: Simulator,
    val useEm: () => Unit) {

  def this(sim: Simulator)(cmhs: Seq[CMH[sim.type,_]]) = {
    this(sim, () => cmhs foreach { cmh => sim.useCM(cmh.cm) })
  }

  useEm()

}
```

And use it:

```
object Test extends Simulator {
  type CM[T] = Option[T]
  def useCM(v: CM[_]) = println(v)
  def mkCM[T]: CM[T] = None

  val cm = CMH(mkCM[AnyRef])

  new SimIterator(this)(cm :: Nil)
}
```