# Scala type projection

Tags: scala

I have a collection of models, each of which exposes a next(...) method which moves the model forward by a discrete step.  Each next() method has a parameter given by the abstract type T.

I want to be able to wrap each model with another class, where the wrapper will also inherit the type T (which is different for each model), but provide additional logic.  This would be trivial by letting the wrapper also extend a model, but this is not feasible with the internal logic of my actual model implementations.

My solution would be to use type projections like so:

```
trait Model {
  type T // works fine when this is a concrete implementation, but then cannot be overridden
  def next(input : T) = println(input)
}

abstract class Parent {
  type S <: Model
  type T = S#T
  val model : S
  def next(input : T) = model.next(input) 
}
```

This fails with the compiler error: *type mismatch;  found   : input.type (with underlying type Parent.this.T)  required: Parent.this.model.T*

Note that in any concrete implementation of Parent, Parent.this.T should be equal to Parent.this.model.T.

So far my workaround is to abandon using the type system, and just creating unique Parent classes for each Model (ie duplicating all of the other logic that a Parent may expose).  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: To fix error just replace `type T = S#T` with `type T = model.T`, but I can't understand your goal.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not allow multiple sub classes of Model to provide their own type T, or more specifically, the compiler will allow one instance of Model to provide a type T, but then no further Models can be produced without generating compiler errors.

Comment: You have 2 models: with `T = Int` and `T = String`, how could they be compatible?

Comment: The separate models never see each other, all Parent.next() does is pass a message onto its Models... ParentString.next(x : String) passes to ModelString.next(x : String) and ParentInt(x : Int) passes to ModelInt.next(x : Int).  It could be done by allowing Parent.next() to take Any, but that defeats the point of a type system.

Answer (score 3):

Credits go to @senia. Setting `type T = model.T` works just fine:

```
abstract class Parent {
  type S <: Model
  type T = model.T
  val model : S
  def next(input : T) = model.next(input) 
}

class SimpleParent[GT <: Model](val model: GT) extends Parent {
  type S = GT
}

trait StringModel extends Model { type T = String }
trait IntModel    extends Model { type T = Int }

object Test {
  new SimpleParent(new StringModel {})
  new SimpleParent(new IntModel {})
}
```

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244499/scala-re-use-generic-resulting-from-path-dependent-type-in-path-dependent-conte), to see why `type T = S#T` doesn't work. (Short version: We could have `model.type <: S` and `S#T` not concrete, hence `S#T` could be incompatible with `model.T`).